# Hex to decimal conversion

Tags: base-conversion

I'm converting hex ( in positional fractions) to decimal

question : 0x3c.e8

my attempt:
$3*16^1 + 12*16^0$  yields $60$

$ 3c$ = $ 60 $  in decimal so i know its 60.

then $.e8 *10 $ (since I want base ten) = $232$

my question is do I just say 60.232?

Comment: 3C.E8 = 0x3C + 0xE8 / 0x100 = 60 + 232/256 = 60.90625

Comment: how do you know to divide by 256?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The respective weights of the hex digits are (in decimal)

$$16,1,\frac1{16},\frac1{256},$$

hence

$$3\cdot 16+12\cdot1+\frac{14}{16}+\frac{8}{256}.$$